# Cannot Access values of a Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm developing a webApp using React, I'm having issues accessing data inside a javascript Object, here is the code:

```
      const user_position = System.prototype.getUserPosition();

console.log({user_position:user_position,latitude:user_position.latitude,longitude:user_position["longitude"]})

        position_update.latitude = user_position.latitude;
        position_update.longitude = user_position.longitude;
        position_update.timestamp = user_position.timestamp

        this.setState({currentSearchSelection: "La tua posizione"});
```

I want to access the data inside the user_position Object, but the output is quite strange:

```
{user_position: {…}, latitude: undefined, longitude: undefined}
latitude: undefined
longitude: undefined
user_position:
latitude: 41.818550699999996
longitude: 12.495401099999999
timestamp: 1587660938111
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

Basically, the user_position is populated but I cannot access the values inside it, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: do `console.log("user_position:",user_position)` to get a better look, or even `console.log("keys:",Object.keys(user_position))` to see the keys inside. The object does seem to be defined but you can't see the details from your current log statement.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the name of the exact values in the object, you can get it directly:
`console.log(user_position.object_name)`

Right now it is saying that your user_position is an object, and is defined.

Maybe even try just print that user_object
`console.log(user_object)` to see what is in it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for the support, the answer was simple: the `getUserPosition()` method was async(even it was not marked as it), so there was nothing wrong in the code of this particular class, what happened was:

```
    user_position.object_name // print undefined since user_position is not populated

    user_position // print value because the variable is linked to the result of the async method
```

So what I did was editing the code with a callback:

```
System.prototype.getUserPosition().then(user_position=>{

        position_update.latitude = user_position.latitude;
        position_update.longitude = user_position.longitude;
        position_update.timestamp = user_position.timestamp

        this.setState({currentSearchSelection: "La tua posizione"});
})
```

and everything worked.

Comment: if previous answers was helpful you better upvote them